# Blacklist or whitelist approach to filtering?

Tags: algorithm, filter, web

I'm testing mobile internet and noticed the provider is using a filter for senstive content.

What approach are they using exactly ? Would it be a whitelist ? Because I imagine it might be impractical to screen all sites while haveing the risk of a child ending up on a site they shouldn't be on.

Or would they be using a third approach ? Say, a clever filter that scans for words and weights results.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right place to ask? It's not a programming question or [an actual problem that you face.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @boj It's of interest to me for creating a filtering system. No need to reinvent the wheel if it exists and curiosity is a good thing :) . Do not know if there is an SE site that is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Neither; do sanitization: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation#Sanitize

Doing both blacklists/whitelists leaves you in a "circle" of constant updating and management along with other issues.

Comment: Interesting link there. The content also appears to be saying that whitelist sanitization is the better approach. Curious to know how this would work from a URL/page content point of view.

Answer (score 1):

There are companies that sell ready-made databases categorising sites by type. Then your provider would just decide which categories they want to let through and which to block - see e.g. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207145.aspx "URL filtering is subscription based, and is part of the Forefront TMG Web Security Service license."

Of course the reputation of such schemes is pretty poor, with problems from towns such as Scunthorpe or people selling wristwatches (bad words embedded in the name) or sites about various cancers (on the assumption that anything about those body parts must be naughty).

Congratulations to Stack Overflow if this post gets through - although I have tried to make its job as easy as possible.

Comment: "the reputation of such schemes is pretty poor"

Yes, I imagine it would have it's flaws. I'm guessing such services use an approach where a site would be blocked if in doubt. Hence the  examples you've given.

Comment: Here is a link to a service associated with Symantec, and an argument over the categorisation of a particular site: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/02/11/mens_rights_site_blacklist/